# Python pip broken after OS X 10.8 upgrade

Tags: python, macos, pip

Made the upgrade to Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and get now the following error when trying to call `$ pip`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.1
```

Update: Tried to reinstall by doing the install procedure again (with http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer and `easy_install`), but didn't work, got the same error.

Tried now the following: Calling `$ sudo pip` and the above error disappears. Strange is, that the directories which could not befound in the above error message point to /System/Library/... while the python installation is (new ?) to find in /Library/Frameworks/..:

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

Any idea how to get rid of the sudo?

Comment: Probably just `root` having a different `$PATH`.  You have two copies of Python installed and you're not being careful as to which version you use.  Either use the Apple Python (in /System and /usr) or one you installed; take a look at the first line of scripts like `pip` to see which one it's using.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use `easy_install` to update your `pip` to the latest version:

`sudo easy_install -U pip`

Also make sure you have the lastest `XCode` installed (ver 4.4) with `Command Line Tools`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I can't see why this approach should change something vs. re-installing pip with the pip-installer (http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Tried it and get the same error, but tried something else and get for the moment a work around, but ugly (see updated question).

Comment: This will work because pip depend on some of the XCode Command Line Tools. However, XCode need to be re-installed after upgrading to Mountain Lion. I tried the approach myself and it works.

Comment: Had the same idea, did it twice, first over the App Store, then by downloading it and installing it "manually". Also started it up and installed the Command Line Package over the Preferences. Strange, that it works with sudo, but not without.

Comment: @gereon what's the error message if running without sudo? DistributionNotFound? Permission Denied? If it's the latter, chmod the necessary dir/files the error message points to.

Comment: I'm still getting the DistributionNotFound error when I run sudo easy_install pip (with or without the -U). Can anyone help please?

Comment: similar error with Trac after upgrading to mountain lion: sudo easy_install -U Trac

Comment: easy_install is broken too.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/easy_install
brew reinstall python
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This worked for me after I somehow broke pip after trying to upgrade it. I'm on OSX 10.11.6  Looks like I had python 2.7 and 3.x installed, now looks like I have just 3.7 and things seem to work fine.

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.14 and this worked for me, however, I had to change 'pip' to 'pip3' because 2.7 is also installed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error except that `sudo pip` did not work either. I am using a "brew" installation of python (which is symlinked to /usr/local/bin) and found that the problem was that the shebangs in the pip and easy_install files were hardcoded to `#!/usr/bin/python` instead of `#!/usr/local/bin/python`, and so was using the system python version instead of the brew version.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Which files/where were these files?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Demis, but FWIW they are in /usr/local/bin. You run the command "which pip" or "which easy_install" to be sure

Answer (score 3):

I actually couldn't do what was suggested.  I instead had to execute:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then I was able to install the ldap module.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers here, from reinstall easy_install to install a new python version, nothing worked for me.

What I did was install a fresh Python install in the /Library/Frameworks folder, and symlink to that one from /usr/local/bin (for some reason, my system had a symlink from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework to /System/Frameworks/Python.framework). My idea was to keep the /System/Library/Frameworks files to be used by system commands in /usr/bin, and have /usr/local/bin points to another "user land" install in /Library/Frameworks. In order to do that :

- rename /System/Library/Framework/Python.framework into _OLD_Python.framework
- delete every python file in /usr/local/bin (using sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*) and /usr/local/bin/pip* (but do NOT touch /usr/bin)
- Reinstall python from the official site (http://www.python.org/getit/)
  ==> This will reinstall python in /Library/Framework and not /System/Library/Framework
- Then launch the Applications/Python/Update Shell Profile.command command that will make sure your path is using that one
- Then recreate the symlinks in /usr/local/bin using

  ln -s ../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python python
- Finaly, rename the _OLD_Python.framework back to Python.framework (because that's the path  /usr/bin/python points to)

Typing "which python" should point to /Library/...  and not /System/Library. From there you should be able to reinstall easy_install and pip properly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change ownership, it is possible to simply change permissions:

$ sudo chmod -R o+rX /Library/Python/2.7/site.packages

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks, I found that

```
ls -l `which python`
/usr/local/bin/python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

while pip showed

```
ls -l `which pip`
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

I renamed the old `pip` and created a symlink to the proper pip binary, and now all is well. It's probably not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reinstalling python with homebrew:  `brew install python`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permissions for Python folder (from root to my user), and now everything work for me:

```
sudo chown -R <your_user>:wheel /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Not recommended for machines with multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I usually had same issue with some project referencing `bonjour-py` in their `requirements.txt`, didn't know which or how to track that one at the moment.

And someone told me that **[pip-tool](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools)**. It's actually a great alternative to identify which you have, and if you want to update them. And as a bonus it ignored well the `bonjour-py` error.