# My ipython and libraries disabled after installing OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion

I have a problem similar to this one below:

[Python pip broken after OS X 10.8 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704379/python-pip-broken-after-os-x-10-8-upgrade)

After installing ML, I can no longer use iPython, SciPy or Matplotlib. I get this error:

```
Shanes-MacBook-Pro:~ $ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ipython==0.14.dev
```

I have tried the following to fix it:

- Using sudo ipython
- Installing latest Xcode
- Reinstalling [SciPy superpack](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack)

When I type which python it says it is in `/usr/bin/python`.

Extra information:

nside /Library/python/2.7/site-packages

Inside there is the following:

```
DateUtils-0.5.2-py2.7.egg
README
easy-install.pth
nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg
pika-0.9.5-py2.7.egg
pyzmq-2.2.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
tornado-2.3-py2.7.egg
```

So with this ML upgrade, it removed my numpy, ipython, etc. And it does not install there anymore like it did with lion. How can I find where it installs too because it seems like it is working when I run the install_superpack shell script.

Comment: From a python interactive shell, can you try `import IPython` and make sure everything is properly installed. Do you know if you have any other versions of Python installed in your system, from what I can tell that version of python is Apple's Python, known to have some issues with Matplotlib, SciPy and NumPy. If you had another python installed it would probably be at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`.

Comment: No I guess it is not installed properly. Yes I do have lots of versions of python installed. My directory tree is not exactly what you have there. Mine is this:  /Library/python/2.7/site-packages

Comment: I cannot test this suggestion right now, but if you: Downloaded and installed Python from python.org, then ran easy_install to install all of iPython's dependencies you should be ready to go and for Numpy and Matplotlib I would suggest you use the dmgs located in each of the project's download sites. I presonally don't like the superpack but then again it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your help El Developer (especially with formatting my comments and answers). I now have an academic license of the Enthought Python Distribution (http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) containing the libraries I want and it works great. I am now free to enjoy my Mountain Lion. Should I delete my post or modify it further? Thanks.

Comment: Well the question still exists as it is ... it would be your choice. Nonetheless when closing a question you will be required for others to vote to close it.

Comment: FWIW http://pebkac.homelinux.net/2012/07/28/python-virtualenv-after-mountain-lion-upgrade/ gave me my fix, which was installing pip using the system /usr/bin/easy_install rather than letting my /usr/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/easy_install duke it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update, I never fixed this specific problem. However, I just downloaded the iPython, SciPy, Matplotlib etc. from Enthought. I answered someone elses question on how to do this here:

[How to check whether I have IPython installed on my machine and what sequence to install these libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361500/how-to-check-whether-i-have-ipython-installed-on-my-machine-and-what-sequence-to/12361575#12361575)