# After OSX 10.11 upgrade, PIP not found

Tags: python, macos, pip

After upgrading to El Capitan on OSX, trying to execute a `pip` command, such as `pip install simplejson` no longer works - I get this error `-bash: pip: command not found`

I tried to re-install `pip` using the 'get-pip.py' script (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).  Running that command returns this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
```

However, I still can not call `pip` from terminal.  What should I do to make the `pip` command work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip broken after OS X 10.8 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704379/python-pip-broken-after-os-x-10-8-upgrade)

Comment: You may want to be more specific here: `[...] calling pip no longer works`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a binary or symlink "pip" anywhere, you may need to use a symlink as you said. I would make the symlink in /usr/local/bin and not /usr/bin this time.

Is it possible, for whatever reason, there was a symbolic link for pip in /usr/bin before you updated?  If this is the case then the system may have deleted it while modifying the /usr/bin folder during an upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mess with this manually. `brew` is a package manager and is in charge of what happens in `/usr/local/bin`. You should avoid creating and deleting files there.